# Manifest does not force Visual Studio 2013 to restart under Admin when running application in Debug mode

Tags: manifest, visual-studio-2013

This worked in *VS2010* and *VS2012*. But in *VS2013* application (by pressing "Run" or *F5*) is just starts with my user's rights and cannot access some resources (I'm using HttpListener).

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

I tried to google, tried to generate new manifest, copied it's content from MSDN, but nothing helped. Did something changed in this part of *VS2013*?

**Update1:**
That was a part. Here is complete manifest content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>

<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
  <application></application>
</compatibility>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

**Update2:**
Okey here is simple example: when I run compiled .exe file UAC asks for admin privileges. But when I run it from *VS2013* (by pressing "Run" or *F5*) it doesn't! And if you open the same project with *VS2012/VS2010*, they do ask to restart under admin.
  You can check this quickly:
Create console application in *VS2013*, add manifest and set **level="requireAdministrator"**. Then run or press *F5* (*VS2013* runs the application under admin when press *Ctrl-F5*).
  But this is not the behavior of *VS2012/VS2010*!
  How can we get the old behavior?

**Update3:**
Please vote [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805985/vs-does-not-suggest-to-launch-elevated-when-the-developed-application-require-elevation) or inform me about another ticket.

Comment: I've just noticed this today as well. Haven't been able to find any information on it. For now I'm just starting VS 2013 as administrator, but it would definitely be nice to bring back the old behavior so that I don't have to remember to do it myself.

Comment: Same problem here too. When I start the solution with VS2012 it asks for a restart. So my manifest is good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to disable the hosting process option to get the VS restart prompt.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox.  It can be easier to just start VS elevated right away.  Right-click the shortcut, Run as Administrator.

Not entirely sure if this is a bug or a feature.  Keep your eye on [this Connect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805985/vs-does-not-suggest-to-launch-elevated-when-the-developed-application-require-elevation) to learn more.

---

Update: looks like a bug, the feedback report was closed as "fixed".  Unfortunately it gives no hint when that fix is going to make it our machines.  Maybe a future VS2013 update, surely the next version.
Update2: the fix made it into VS2013 Update 3.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the code: XmlElement useVSHostingProcessElement = doc.CreateElement("UseVSHostingProcess", NS);
                    useVSHostingProcessElement.InnerText = "false";
                    el.AppendChild(useVSHostingProcessElement);

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is I run the project without debugging `CRTL+F5` . The it gives me the same prompt that Visual Studio 2010 gives you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping this will get fixed soon™
In the mean time you can use handy shortcuts for restarting VS in admin mode, look up "Visual Studio Restart" in the extension gallery.

Edit:

Only way I see you can achieve the old behavior is to turn off VS hosting process as it is this process that for some reason "eats" the elevation prompt. Actually when I think about it, this behavior might even be by design. You can turn off hosting process in project properties (Debug) or when you generate .csproj set platform configuration UseVSHostingProcess tag to false, like so:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Our scenario is next: user installs our Engine, runs VS and generates new HttpListener-based project with help of our Wizard. Then he (she) starts the project and VS asks to restart in admin mode.

Comment: Can you maybe mark my post as answer as I showed how the old behavior can be replicated (with minimal side effects) before anyone else in this thread (including edit)?