# App Manifest Ignored

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, manifest, windows-7-x64

I am developing an app in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 x64 that requires administrator privileges but it appears my manifest is being ignored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
      Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows Vista, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8.1, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
   <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

To test my theory, I put in some invalid text to see if the parser would crash, but nothing happened. I have tried building as Any CPU, x86, and x64 with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lots of reasons a manifest won't be seen by Windows, you didn't post enough details.  Starting point is Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick the hosting process option so it looks for a manifest in yourapp.exe instead of yourapp.vshost.exe

Comment: I unticked hosting process and then ran the my app outside of Visual Studio and it presented me with a UAC prompt. Is there any reason that it would not present the UAC prompt while running through Visual Studio's debugger?

Comment: Not when you've disabled the hosting process.  Maybe you are already running VS elevated, it is common.

Comment: I seem to have gotten the prompt working. I started Visual Studio un-elevated and it prompted me to restart elevated. Then I ran the application and it performed the elevated tasks correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manifest does not force Visual Studio 2013 to restart under Admin when running application in Debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692516/manifest-does-not-force-visual-studio-2013-to-restart-under-admin-when-running-a)

Comment: I have faced the same problem. Now, I have did all the changed as mentioned above and tried to run the .exe file of my application. Still it runs directly w/o asking for Admin Rights. What would be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you like me removed the manifest and restored it back via source control, your app has likely selected the default-settings-manifest and will ignore all further changes to your custom app.manifest file.

To resolve the problem:

1. Right click your project
2. Click properties
3. Find the Icons and Manifest section
4. Specify the app.manifest in the drop-down
5. Save changes

[image]