# Visual Studio causing embedded assembly manifest to be ignored while debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, com, registration-free-com

My .NET client application has a dependancy on another assembly. This dependancy is declared in an `app.manifest` file:

**app.manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="Contoso.Frobber.Admin"/>

  <!-- We have a dependancy on Grobber -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Contoso.Grobber" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- Windows 7-->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>

</asmv1:assembly>
```

And then the project is configured to use our `app.manifest` file. You specify the use of the custom `app.manifest` under **Project** -> **Application** -> **Resources**:

[image]

## And it all works

I have to be sure to place my other assembly in the same folder^1. For example:

**Contoso.Grobber.manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">

  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Contoso.Grobber" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" />

  <file name = "Grobberify.dll">
    <comClass
          progid="Contoso.Grobberify"
          clsid="{EB4B9718-0625-4505-BBF2-42CF7E94643E}"
          description="Grobber system frobs"
          threadingModel = "Apartment" />
  </file>
</assembly>
```

So i have in my folder:

- SampleApplication.exe
- Contoso.Grobber.Manifest
- Grobberify.dll

And everything works. My application runs, and everything behaves correctly.

I can prove that my embedded manifest is being honored, because if i change my embedded manifest to require something called <strike>Contoso.Grobber</strike> **asdfasfaraasdf**:

```
  <!-- We have a dependancy on Grobber -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="asdfasfaraasdf" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

If run my application now, the Fusion loader will realize that there is no assembly called **asdfasfaraasdf**, and throw an error while loading:

[image]

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

And if i put my dependant assembly back to the correct <strike>asdfasfaraasdf</strike> --> **Contso.Grobber** then everything works.

### Except when debugging

For no particular reason, if i am inside the **debugger** then the fusion loader is not seeing my assembly manifest and it's dependant assemblies.

I can prove this by declaring in my assembly manifest that i depend on an assembly that doesn't exist (e.g. name="asdfasdfasf")

```
![enter image description here][3]
```

The application should fail to launch - **but it launches**! No matter what i do:

- use a fake assembly name
- delete the manifest of my depenent assembly
- delete the `.dll` of my dependant assembly

The application does **not** fail to launch. That means that whatever version of my executable that Visual Studio is running: it does not contain my embedded `app.manifest`.

### It's a problem because it's broken

You might think that having an application run is a good thing - i wouldn't *want* it to fail. That is wrong for two reasons:

- i **want** it to fail to launch if a required assembly is not present
- the dependent assembly contains required fusion information

The assembly i am loading is a COM dll. My `.manifest` file contains much needed COM `clsid` and filename information. When Visual Studio does not honor my application manifest, the Fusion loader will not see my registration-free COM objects:

```
<comClass
      progid="Contoso.Grobberify"
      clsid="{EB4B9718-0625-4505-BBF2-42CF7E94643E}"
      description="Grobber system frobs"
      threadingModel = "Apartment" />
  </file>
```

Without this assembly comClass information, my .NET application cannot create the COM object while debugging:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("EB4B9718-0625-4505-BBF2-42CF7E94643E")]
public class Grabasstic
{
}

IGrobberAss ga = (IGrobberAss)new Grabasstic();
```

[image]

### It only happens when debugging

This failure of Visual Studio Community 2013 on Windows 7 64-bit with a 32-bit application, with a logged-in user who has no wallpaper configured only happens while debugging the application. If i run the **SampleApplication.exe** directly, the embedded assembly manifest **is** honored.

It might have something to do with the fact that Visual Studio doesn't debug

> **SampleApplication.exe**

Visual Studio actually debugs an application called:

> **SampleApplication.vshost.exe**

Or not. What do i know?

## How do i make it work?

I know there's no solution. The volume of people on the planet who have any experience with [registration-free COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) is limited to:

- [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162817/registration-free-com-from-asp-net)
- [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)
- [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/06/10291324.aspx)

It's safe to say that nobody actually read the **entire** block of *"Research Effort"* above. I'm also curious to see which users caught the easter-egg up there, as well as who will complain about *too much* research effort.

In reality, i know there is no solution. And while i can document the fact that this a problem, i am under no allusions that anyone can solve it. Which makes this entire 45 minute question a way for me to vent about unsolvable problems.

## Bonus Reading

- [Here's a guy who's embedded manifest is also being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22149863/12597). For him it is causing the application to not honor his `requireAdministrator` security entry
- [Manifest does not force Visual Studio 2013 to restart under Admin when running application in Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692516/manifest-does-not-force-visual-studio-2013-to-restart-under-admin-when-running-a)
- [App Manifest Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149863/app-manifest-ignored)
- [Visual Studio causing embedded assembly manifest to be ignored while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603391/visual-studio-causing-embedded-assembly-manifest-to-be-ignored-while-debugging)

Comment: You are not actually using the embedded manifest when you debug.  The bin\Debug\SampleApplication.vshost.exe.manifest file on disk will be used instead.  Something wrong with it, have a look at it.  Fwiw, naming it Contoso.Grobber.Manifest and showing a screenshot for app.manifest doesn't help us help you.  Also consider disabling the hosting process so this just can't be an issue.

Comment: @HansPassant That's because there really **are** two manifests involved. One is the host executable (`SampleApplication.exe`) and its embedded manifest (`app.manifest`). The other is the separate dll (`Contoso.Grobber.dll`) and it's (external) assembly manifest (`Contoso.Grobber.manifest`).

Comment: Actually, I can't replicate this problem in Visual Studio **2012**, it might be a regression in **2013**.  That is, when I change the manifest to depend on a non-existent assembly, or declare `requireAdministrator`, going to DEBUG > Start Debugging shows immediate effects, e.g. failed loading, or the UAC prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution **was** to disable the **Visual Studio hosting process** from **Project** -> ***Project* Properties**:

[image]

Based on the MSDN [documentation of the Hosting Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185331(v=vs.100).aspx), it has no real value to developers, and can safely be turned off.

Comment: Did you try deleting the *.vshost.exe before building and debugging again?

Comment: This fixed my own issue: I embed four sub-project assemblies in the main assembly but during debug I had to clean the solution each time before running so that the auto-incremented assembly version revisions would be the same as the sub-assembly builds. A huge PITA. Disabling the VS Host Process in each project fixed this in VS2013. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete the *.vshost.exe file.  Windows caches manifest information per binary file (EXE, DLL), so it'll use the first configuration used with the *.vshost.exe file.

This doesn't happen if you launch your application or if you don't use the Visual Studio host, because your binaries change when recompiling.  However, the *.vshost.exe file is not modified or touched at all.

You must manually delete it and let Visual Studio recreate/copy it again.  Or better yet, try without the Visual Studio host.

Here's a proper reference: [Windows Vista Sxs Activation Context Cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/10/01/vista-activation-context-cache.aspx).  I assume things still work this way in 8.1 and in the upcoming 10.

Comment: I upvoted to counteract the anonymous downvote. I didn't try deleting VSHost and trying again. I just stopped using the host processes and went on my way. I don't believe that visual studio builds *my* manifest into their hosting exe.

Comment: It doesn't, but the *.vhost.exe file doesn't have an embeded manifest and VS copies your manifest to *.vhost.exe.manifest on (re)build.